# Name for Turning DAG into redundant tree

Tags: trees, spanning-trees, dag

I am looking for a term:

How is the tree called that you can obtain from a DAG by going top-down and appending all visited nodes to a tree, thereby copying nodes from the DAG into multiple occurences in the tree?

The resulting tree will contain all edges and nodes from the original DAG and a number of nodes multiple times.

```
A -> B
|    |
v    v
C -> D
```

Will be turned into:

```
A -> B -> D
|
v
C
|
v
D
```

If you need clarifications, please ask.

Comment: So the resulting tree is supposed to contain every path of the original DAG or how exactly does one construct your resulting tree?

Comment: @rex123 I'm thinking OP might be talking about the tree $T$ of all reachable paths starting from a selected vertex $A$ in an input DAG. Each node correspond to a path that starts from $A$ and each edge in $T$ correspond to the relationship that a path extends to become another one.

Comment: If one try to list all paths in DAG without the common starting point condition, there might be two paths that one can not extends to become another.

Comment: The resulting tree is supposed to contain every path of the original DAG.

Comment: If it makes things easier, consider the DAG to be a set of semilattices.

Comment: Haven't seen or read an explicit name for that kind of tree. Maybe name it _tree of all paths_?

Comment: I was looking to find some implementations, of course I could do it myself but I think it would go well alongside other spanning  trees in some collections...

Comment: The thing is, as you said yourself, this kind of tree is very redundant and essentially any graph or DAG already contains the information of _all paths_ implicitly in it. So maybe you should ask what problem you eventually want to solve.

Comment: @rex123 I see your point. So find all nodes with zero incoming edges and perform top-down traversal?

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any standard name for that kind of tree.  One of the wonderful things about language is that we can describe things we don't already have a name for; there are many more interesting concepts than there are pre-existing widely-recognized names.  I recommend that, if you find in your writing you need a concise name for it, you choose a name that seems suitable to you, and define it before first use.